# Load database value to text box when a button click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I’ working on a PHP web application and I have mySQL database. After entering the ‘name’ and clicking on the button called ‘select’, I want to find the minimum value of ‘id’ and put that minimum value to a text box called "min". 
This is my code so far.It works perfectly.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php

    include('config.php');
    $id='';
    $query1='';
    $name='';
    if(isset($_POST['select']))
    {
      $name=$_POST['name'];
      $query1=mysql_query("select MIN(id) as id1 from places where name='$name'");
      while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
      {
        $id=$query2['id1'];
      }
    }
    echo'<form method="post" >';
    echo 'name<input type="text" name="name" value="' .  $name . '">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="select" value="select"><br>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="min" value="' .  $id . '">';
    echo'</form>';
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But It refreshes the page once clicking on the button. I want to do this without refreshing the page. I heard that AJAX can do the same without refreshing the page. I tried, but didn’t work. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: " I tried, but didn’t work", Add the code that you used to try it.

Comment: Not related, but never use post into a sql query without escaping

Answer (score 1):

try this

index.html code

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<input type="text" name="min" id="min" value="">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="select">
<script>
    $('#submit').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $name=$('#name').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {"name": $name},
          url: 'select.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#min').val(data.r_id);
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and select.php on same directory

```
<?php

include('config.php');
if($_POST)
{
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $query1=mysql_query("select MIN(id) as id1 from places where name='$name'");
  while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
  {
    $id=$query2['id1'];
  }
  $response=array(
            'r_id'=>$id,
            );  
}
print json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: @ Niroj Adhikary. Thanks a lot for helping me. I tried what you said. But it didn't work.

Comment: did you link jquery on your html page?

Comment: this code is working fine here. use debugging tool and check there .

Comment: @ Niroj, can you please tell me, should I add the ajax part after the <form> </form> or inside the <head></head> ? can you please send me your full code of index.php?

Comment: check the index.html part (updated) in above answer .its not standard way but it should work

Comment: @Niroj, Ok. I'll try. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Akhil, Ok. I'll try. Thanks for helping me.